# How to make a function to assign points to the current player during their turn

Tags: javascript

I've done a game in js that works well with 2 players, but I want to add the functionality of letting the user add up to 5 players, so how can I check who's player turn is it to properly assign the points to them if the number of players will be user-defined?

My code now is hard-coded for two teams :

```js
//team 1
let team1Points = 0;
//team 2
let team2Points = 0;

let whoPlayed = 0;

//assign points to a Team
function assignPoints(points) {
  //check who's turn is it
  switch (whoPlayed) {
    case 0:
      team1Points += points;
      whoPlayed++;
      break;
    case 1:
      team2Points += points;
      whoPlayed--;
      break;
  }
}

assignPoints(2);
assignPoints(3);
console.log(team1Points);
console.log(team2Points);
```

Comment: Store teams in array, so it can have any no of teams, then store index of playing in whoplayed var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array instead:

```js
const NUM_PLAYERS = 5;

// Make an array filled with 0s, with a length of NUM_PLAYERS:
const scores = Array.from({ length: NUM_PLAYERS }, () => 0);

let activePlayerIndex = 0;

//assign points to a Team
function assignPoints(points) {
  scores[activePlayerIndex] += points;
  activePlayerIndex = (activePlayerIndex + 1) % NUM_PLAYERS;
}

assignPoints(2);
assignPoints(3);
assignPoints(66);
assignPoints(0);
assignPoints(1);
assignPoints(5);

console.log(scores);
```

Above, `scores[0]` will correspond to the number of points the first player has, `scores[1]` will correspond to the number of points the second player has, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works, however I don't understand the logic behind this line "activePlayerIndex = (activePlayerIndex + 1) % NUM_PLAYERS;" . If you have time could you explain? Thanks again.

Comment: It means that `activePlayerIndex` will rotate between, eg, `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `0` `1` etc. It adds one to the previous value and then calls modulo on the result. If there are 5 players, then that's modulo 5, so it starts from 0 again after the 5th player.